# Is inclusiveness range of end determined by rule or convention?

Tags: semantics, irregular, range-inclusion

Are there explicit rules for how ranges are communicated, or must they be understood by context or convention?

Examples:

- If a store is open 9am-5pm, we assume the end of the period (5) is exclusive. I need to be out *before* 5pm.
- 2nd world war was from 1939 to 1945. It ended on September 30, 1945. So the "1945" is inclusive.
- If I'm invited to stay with a friend in their home Friday-Sunday, it is assumed I need to leave sometime during Sunday. The "Sunday" is inclusive.
- If something is 5-8ft long, it can never be more than 8ft. The "8" is exclusive.

Comment: I think there's a typo: patter? or **pattern*?

Comment: Ranges do not follow rules. English isn’t algebra. Often, as you say, context or convention will dictate, but there are still a number of situations where there is no overarching guidance, and the language is simply ambiguous, and the only solution is to *ask* the person who specified the range.

Comment: This is English!  There are no rules!

Comment: A plank 8ft 0.2 inch would doubtless be sorted into the '5 - 8ft' pile. Rounding needs to be taken into account; pragmatic interpretation in everyday language is different from precisionist interpretation.

Comment: If a business is open 9am-5pm you have a range between 2 points in time. In practice its doors aren't driven by a satellite or internet time signal and it's going to vary somewhat: some will let you stay a few minutes after to finish up, some will have you out the door at quarter to, and a cafe might stop serving at 4:30. This is why it depends on practice, convention, and margins of error.

Comment: Setting aside the very apt comment by Stuart F, and interpreting the 9AM-5PM example strictly, it is not clear how the question of inclusiveness/exclusiveness would even arise when the limits of the range are specified in such a way. What would it mean for the precise moment of 5PM to be either included or excluded in the range?

Comment: jsw29 perhaps "included" is not the right word, but rather having the end number be interpreted as a range itself. 9AM-5PM would then mean a range starting at 9 and ending sometime within the range that is 5.00-5.59PM. It is in this way that 2nd world war was 1939 to 1945, where 1945 is considered a range in its own right. I have no issue with this, the question is rather if there is any kind of understanding to fall back on. So far, it seems the answer is "no".

Comment: @mikabytes, indeed, ranges are ambiguous when their limits are specified in terms of something that is itself a range (a day, a year, etc.), but not when they are specified in terms of **moments**, or **points**. Because of that, the first and the fourth example in the question are not really relevant to it.

Comment: @jsw29 That is precisely the issue. The answer to this question is "no" because English lacks a way of expressing a moment/point. Everything is a range if you decide to interpret it so. There's no issue with the start of the range because any possible range interpretation of it is also included in the "bigger" range being expressed. This is not so with the end range. So we get ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your examples can be taken as inclusive of both ends. For example, the store closing time can be read as “leave *by* 5pm”.

There is no general convention regarding inclusion or exclusion of the end points, but context and convention can favour one or the other.

If you write the range out with words, you can be more prescriptive:

- Get there by noon.
- Get there before noon.
- Get there after noon.

Typically, if the end point is itself a fairly broad range, it would be inclusive, but even that isn’t conclusive. “Between the ages of 30 and 40” has a whole year at each end point. If you were 30 years and 6 months old, you’d be included. If you were 40 years and 6 months old, though, you’d need to check whether the rules / convention cut off the range at the moment you turn 40, or whether you have to be 41 to fall outside the range.

One way people get around this is to add “exclusive” or “inclusive” after the range.

Comment: Appreciate the encouragement to use clearer language.

Comment: Yes, inclusion and exclusion. Not inclusiveness which refers to human behavior.